# What would you call a person who knows nothing but will say i knew it all along (on a topic being discussed)?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

What would you call a person who knows nothing on a topic being discussed but will say i knew it beforehand (probably fake a story on same lines in boasting manner) and really isn't inclined on learning anything new and does want to feel inferior and still wants to keep claiming s/he knew it but will not like being asked questions if you want to dig them deeper for sincerity ?

Example:

> Me: The apple is acidic fruit, I read it in an article today.
>   B: Yes, I know it is acidic.
>   B: My local specialist doctor who is very famous and US return doctor told me when I was 10 years old.
>   Me: Oh ok.
>   Me: I read another thing today, mackrel fish is not good for pregnent women.
>   B: Ya, My mother when she was in Germany, her neighbor told her.
>   Me: Oh ok.
>   Me: The new spinning fidget is nice fun for children.
>   B: Yes, my dad bought it when i was 7 and we (me and my brother) used it during our entire childhood.
>   A: Oh is it. hmm..

Comment: I would suggest a "know it all"

Comment: Wouldn't it be like "know it all" actually knows stuff and s/he likes to boast at every opportunity, while i am looking for an adjective which exposes the "don't know anything" but "show as if know everything" characteristics of a person.

Comment: Look at the wikipedia entry for "know it all". I think it is very close to what you want. The expression "wise guy" is also close.

Comment: You say the person "*does* want to feel inferior" - how does the behaviour you describe accomplish that?

Comment: I would call them a knew-it-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is **pretentious**:

> attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed.

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred to have put this as a comment but I don't have the reputation. I was first inclined to suggest "intellectually insecure" but couldn't find a reliable reference to back this up. After a bit of research it sounds like the person you are describing could be called "[narcissistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder)".

In [Malignant Self Love: Narcissism Revisited, page 171](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Rau68YbcoDEC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=narcissist%20pretending%20knowledge&source=bl&ots=MlRtz9vIE7&sig=-Jgl8lydq7olWp_uV6tO7ARIyp0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ_Ii5tobVAhUDUlAKHe2FAD0Q6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=narcissist%20pretending%20knowledge&f=false) Sam Vaknin states that

> The narcissist often pretends to know everything, in every field of human knowledge and endeavor. He lies and prevaricates to avoid the exposure of his ignorance. He resorts to numerous subterfuges to support his God-like omniscience.

This sounds like the person you have described who pretends to know every fact you have stated and makes up stories to back this up. Wikipedia also says that

> The subtype of "narcissistic vulnerability" entails (on a conscious level) "helplessness, emptiness, low self-esteem, and shame, which can be expressed in the behavior as **being socially avoidant in situations where their self-presentation is not possible so they withdraw, or the approval they need/expect is not being met**."

which sound like the person in your example who doesn't like being asked questions to back up their claims. I only know what my quick search has dug up but the person could possible be a "compensatory narcissist", although this doesn't quite fit the description in your question as Wikipedia defines this as:

> Seeks to counteract or cancel out deep feelings of inferiority and lack of self-esteem; offsets deficits by creating illusions of being superior, exceptional, admirable, noteworthy; self-worth results from self-enhancement.